# How to center a items within a container?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu and I want the items and title to be in the centre of the container as at the moment it's tight up against the left edge. I am not sure how to do this:

Here is code and fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/af3co7h5/

```css
#nav_menu-6 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.widget_title {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#menu-account-footer-1 li {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<aside id="nav_menu-6" class="widget_number_8 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu">
  <h5 class="widget_title">ACCOUNT</h5>
  
  <div class="menu-account-footer-container">
    <ul id="menu-account-footer-1" class="menu">
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7970"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=285">Sign In</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7971"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=6089">Earn Rewards</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7968"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=4561">Manage Subscription</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7969"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1109">FAQs</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7967"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1032">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: Using flexbox, you can center the items vertically or horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your discussions, I guess using `text-align: center` on the parent and `text-align: left` on the child does the trick.

```css
h5, ul {
  margin: 0;
}
.widget_number_8 {
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Here you go:

```css
#nav_menu-6 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.widget_title {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#menu-account-footer-1 li {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

h5, ul {
  margin: 0;
}
.widget_number_8 {
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<aside id="nav_menu-6" class="widget_number_8 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu">
  <h5 class="widget_title">ACCOUNT</h5>
  <div class="menu-account-footer-container">
    <ul id="menu-account-footer-1" class="menu">
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7970"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=285">Sign In</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7971"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=6089">Earn Rewards</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7968"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=4561">Manage Subscription</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7969"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1109">FAQs</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7967"><a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/?page_id=1032">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</aside>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: Hi Praveen, I don't think you understand what I mean. I require the title and the list to be in the centre of the box, at the moment it is on the left

Comment: @BruceyBandit Got it. Simple: Use `margin: auto`. Let me update.

Comment: @BruceyBandit Please kindly check the preview, I have updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: Ah ok, so this is the issue. I can see you used text align centre but my client actually wants the text align to still be left. So what I mean is position it to centre, but keep text align left. I did use text align centre before myself but die to his requirement, that's when I struggled :)

Comment: @BruceyBandit Cool, display it inline block, with a fixed width and then you're good to go. Let me update it.

Comment: @BruceyBandit I have updated the answer and preview. I hope this is what you're expecting and it helps?

Comment: Yeah that looks better, only last thing from what I see, I know account is just off set from the others, would be nice if it's inline with the list items

Comment: Figured it. Thanksfor your help Praveen

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
  border: 2px solid red;
  

}
.gallery{
  border: 2px solid blue;
  max-width: 4rem;
  margin: auto;
  
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
      
       <div class="gallery">one</div>
       <div class="gallery">two</div>
       <div class="gallery">three</div>
      

  </div>
```

Comment: No use when you don't give any explanation and why should the OP take your code? There's no clarity in this answer. Also, this code is a wrong representation. It's affected with divitis. If it's a list, use a list.

Comment: just a touch nothing else one of the concepts of centerizing. Be polite be respectful thankyou